# Product grid won't load, constant spinning and 'Something went wrong'

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1.8

Magento 2.1.8 with the log error:

```
a:4:{i:0;s:175:"Warning: strtoupper() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in /home/mysite/public_html/vendor/magento/module-ui/Component/Listing/Columns/Column.php on line 136";i:1;s:5920:"#0 [internal function]: Magento\Framework\App\ErrorHandler->handler(2, 'strtoupper() ex...', '/home/spoolimpo...', 136, Array)
#1 /home/mysite/public_html/vendor/magento/module-ui/Component/Listing/Columns/Column.php(136): strtoupper(Array)
#2 /home/mysite/public_html/vendor/magento/module-ui/Component/Listing/Columns/Column.php(93): Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Column->applySorting()
#3 /home/mysite/public_html/vendor/magento/module-ui/Controller/Adminhtml/Index/Render.php(54): Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Column->prepare()
#4 /home/mysite/public_html/vendor/magento/module-ui/Controller/Adminhtml/Index/Render.php(52): Magento\Ui\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Render->prepareComponent(Object(Magento\Catalog\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\ProductActions))
#5 /home/mysite/public_html/vendor/magento/module-ui/Controller/Adminhtml/Index/Render.php(52): Magento\Ui\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Render->prepareComponent(Object(Magento\Catalog\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns))
#6 /home/mysite/public_html/vendor/magento/module-ui/Controller/Adminhtml/Index/Render.php(39): Magento\Ui\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Render->prepareComponent(Object(Magento\Ui\Component\Listing))
#7 /home/mysite/public_html/var/generation/Magento/Ui/Controller/Adminhtml/Index/Render/Interceptor.php(24): Magento\Ui\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Render->execute()
#8 /home/mysite/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Action/Action.php(102): Magento\Ui\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Render\Interceptor->execute()
#9 /home/mysite/public_html/vendor/magento/module-backend/App/AbstractAction.php(226): Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#10 /home/mysite/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(74): Magento\Backend\App\AbstractAction->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#11 /home/mysite/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(70): Magento\Ui\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Render\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)
#12 /home/mysite/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(63): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Ui\\Cont...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Ui\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Render\Interceptor), Array, 'adminAuthentica...')
#13 /home/mysite/public_html/vendor/magento/module-backend/App/Action/Plugin/Authentication.php(143): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#14 /home/mysite/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(67): Magento\Backend\App\Action\Plugin\Authentication->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Ui\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Render\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#15 /home/mysite/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Ui\\Cont...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Ui\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Render\Interceptor), Array, 'adminMassaction...')
#16 /home/mysite/public_html/vendor/magento/module-backend/App/Action/Plugin/MassactionKey.php(33): Magento\Ui\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Render\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#17 /home/mysite/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(142): Magento\Backend\App\Action\Plugin\MassactionKey->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Ui\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Render\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#18 /home/mysite/public_html/var/generation/Magento/Ui/Controller/Adminhtml/Index/Render/Interceptor.php(52): Magento\Ui\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Render\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)
#19 /home/mysite/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php(55): Magento\Ui\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Render\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#20 /home/mysite/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(74): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#21 /home/mysite/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(70): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)
#22 /home/mysite/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Framewo...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Array, 'install')
#23 /home/mysite/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Module/Plugin/DbStatusValidator.php(69): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#24 /home/mysite/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(142): Magento\Framework\Module\Plugin\DbStatusValidator->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#25 /home/mysite/public_html/var/generation/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)
#26 /home/mysite/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(135): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#27 /home/mysite/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(258): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
#28 /home/mysite/public_html/index.php(39): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http))
#29 {main}";s:3:"url";s:6122:"/manage/mui/index/render/key/0f0fdab36da6ccb0001602d0fc15bf45b1b1a162d3b8037486251fae44edd916/?namespace=product_listing&filters%5Bplaceholder%5D%5B%5D=true&filters%5Bplaceholder%5D%5B%5D=true&filters%5Bplaceholder%5D%5B%5D=true&filters%5Bplaceholder%5D%5B%5D=true&filters%5Bplaceholder%5D%5B%5D=true&filters%5Bplaceholder%5D%5B%5D=true&filters%5Bplaceholder%5D%5B%5D=true&filters%5Bplaceholder%5D%5B%5D=true&filters%5Bplaceholder%5D%5B%5D=true&filters%5Bplaceholder%5D%5B%5D=true&filters%5Bplaceholder%5D%5B%5D=true&filters%5Bplaceholder%5D%5B%5D=true&filters%5Bplaceholder%5D%5B%5D=true&filters%5Bplaceholder%5D%5B%5D=true&filters%5Bplaceholder%5D%5B%5D=true&filters%5Bplaceholder%5D%5B%5D=true&filters%5Bplaceholder%5D%5B%5D=true&filters%5Bplaceholder%5D%5B%5D=true&filters%5Bplaceholder%5D%5B%5D=true&filters%5Bplaceholder%5D%5B%5D=true&filters%5Bplaceholder%5D%5B%5D=true&filters%5Bplaceholder%5D%5B%5D=true&filters%5Bplaceholder%5D%5B%5D=true&filters%5Bplaceholder%5D%5B%5D=true&filters%5Bplaceholder%5D%5B%5D=true&filters%5Bplaceholder%5D%5B%5D=true&filters%5Bplaceholder%5D%5B%5D=true&filters%5Bplaceholder%5D%5B%5D=true&filters%5Bplaceholder%5D%5B%5D=true&filters%5Bplaceholder%5D%5B%5D=true&filters%5Bplaceholder%5D%5B%5D=true&filters%5Bplaceholder%5D%5B%5D=true&filters%5Bplaceholder%5D%5B%5D=true&filters%5Bplaceholder%5D%5B%5D=true&filters%5Bplaceholder%5D%5B%5D=true&filters%5Bplaceholder%5D%5B%5D=true&filters%5Bplaceholder%5D%5B%5D=true&filters%5Bplaceholder%5D%5B%5D=true&filters%5Bplaceholder%5D%5B%5D=true&filters%5Bplaceholder%5D%5B%5D=true&filters%5Bplaceholder%5D%5B%5D=true&filters%5Bplaceholder%5D%5B%5D=true&filters%5Bplaceholder%5D%5B%5D=true&filters%5Bplaceholder%5D%5B%5D=true&filters%5Bplaceholder%5D%5B%5D=true&filters%5Bplaceholder%5D%5B%5D=true&filters%5Bplaceholder%5D%5B%5D=true&filters%5Bplaceholder%5D%5B%5D=true&filters%5Bplaceholder%5D%5B%5D=true&filters%5Bplaceholder%5D%5B%5D=true&filters%5Bplaceholder%5D%5B%5D=true&filters%5Bplaceholder%5D%5B%5D=true&filters%5Bplaceholder%5D%5B%5D=true&filters%5Bplaceholder%5D%5B%5D=true&filters%5Bplaceholder%5D%5B%5D=true&filters%5Bplaceholder%5D%5B%5D=true&filters%5Bplaceholder%5D%5B%5D=true&filters%5Bplaceholder%5D%5B%5D=true&filters%5Bplaceholder%5D%5B%5D=true&filters%5Bplaceholder%5D%5B%5D=true&filters%5Bplaceholder%5D%5B%5D=true&filters%5Bplaceholder%5D%5B%5D=true&filters%5Bplaceholder%5D%5B%5D=true&filters%5Bplaceholder%5D%5B%5D=true&filters%5Bplaceholder%5D%5B%5D=true&filters%5Bplaceholder%5D%5B%5D=true&filters%5Bplaceholder%5D%5B%5D=true&filters%5Bplaceholder%5D%5B%5D=true&filters%5Bplaceholder%5D%5B%5D=true&filters%5Bplaceholder%5D%5B%5D=true&filters%5Bplaceholder%5D%5B%5D=true&filters%5Bplaceholder%5D%5B%5D=true&filters%5Bplaceholder%5D%5B%5D=true&filters%5Bplaceholder%5D%5B%5D=true&filters%5Bplaceholder%5D%5B%5D=true&filters%5Bplaceholder%5D%5B%5D=true&filters%5Bplaceholder%5D%5B%5D=true&filters%5Bplaceholder%5D%5B%5D=true&filters%5Bplaceholder%5D%5B%5D=true&filters%5Bplaceholder%5D%5B%5D=true&filters%5Bplaceholder%5D%5B%5D=true&filters%5Bplaceholder%5D%5B%5D=true&filters%5Bplaceholder%5D%5B%5D=true&filters%5Bfreeship%5D=1&paging%5BpageSize%5D=20&paging%5Bcurrent%5D=1&sorting%5Bfield%5D=actions&sorting%5Bdirection%5D%5B%5D=false&sorting%5Bdirection%5D%5B%5D=false&sorting%5Bdirection%5D%5B%5D=false&sorting%5Bdirection%5D%5B%5D=false&sorting%5Bdirection%5D%5B%5D=false&sorting%5Bdirection%5D%5B%5D=false&sorting%5Bdirection%5D%5B%5D=false&sorting%5Bdirection%5D%5B%5D=false&sorting%5Bdirection%5D%5B%5D=false&sorting%5Bdirection%5D%5B%5D=false&sorting%5Bdirection%5D%5B%5D=false&sorting%5Bdirection%5D%5B%5D=false&sorting%5Bdirection%5D%5B%5D=false&sorting%5Bdirection%5D%5B%5D=false&sorting%5Bdirection%5D%5B%5D=false&sorting%5Bdirection%5D%5B%5D=false&sorting%5Bdirection%5D%5B%5D=false&sorting%5Bdirection%5D%5B%5D=false&sorting%5Bdirection%5D%5B%5D=false&sorting%5Bdirection%5D%5B%5D=false&sorting%5Bdirection%5D%5B%5D=false&sorting%5Bdirection%5D%5B%5D=false&sorting%5Bdirection%5D%5B%5D=false&sorting%5Bdirection%5D%5B%5D=false&sorting%5Bdirection%5D%5B%5D=false&sorting%5Bdirection%5D%5B%5D=false&sorting%5Bdirection%5D%5B%5D=false&sorting%5Bdirection%5D%5B%5D=false&sorting%5Bdirection%5D%5B%5D=false&sorting%5Bdirection%5D%5B%5D=false&sorting%5Bdirection%5D%5B%5D=false&sorting%5Bdirection%5D%5B%5D=false&sorting%5Bdirection%5D%5B%5D=false&sorting%5Bdirection%5D%5B%5D=false&sorting%5Bdirection%5D%5B%5D=false&sorting%5Bdirection%5D%5B%5D=false&sorting%5Bdirection%5D%5B%5D=false&sorting%5Bdirection%5D%5B%5D=false&sorting%5Bdirection%5D%5B%5D=false&sorting%5Bdirection%5D%5B%5D=false&sorting%5Bdirection%5D%5B%5D=false&sorting%5Bdirection%5D%5B%5D=false&sorting%5Bdirection%5D%5B%5D=false&sorting%5Bdirection%5D%5B%5D=false&sorting%5Bdirection%5D%5B%5D=false&sorting%5Bdirection%5D%5B%5D=false&sorting%5Bdirection%5D%5B%5D=false&sorting%5Bdirection%5D%5B%5D=false&sorting%5Bdirection%5D%5B%5D=false&sorting%5Bdirection%5D%5B%5D=false&sorting%5Bdirection%5D%5B%5D=false&sorting%5Bdirection%5D%5B%5D=false&sorting%5Bdirection%5D%5B%5D=false&sorting%5Bdirection%5D%5B%5D=false&sorting%5Bdirection%5D%5B%5D=false&sorting%5Bdirection%5D%5B%5D=false&sorting%5Bdirection%5D%5B%5D=false&sorting%5Bdirection%5D%5B%5D=false&sorting%5Bdirection%5D%5B%5D=false&sorting%5Bdirection%5D%5B%5D=false&sorting%5Bdirection%5D%5B%5D=false&sorting%5Bdirection%5D%5B%5D=false&sorting%5Bdirection%5D%5B%5D=false&sorting%5Bdirection%5D%5B%5D=false&sorting%5Bdirection%5D%5B%5D=false&sorting%5Bdirection%5D%5B%5D=false&sorting%5Bdirection%5D%5B%5D=false&sorting%5Bdirection%5D%5B%5D=false&sorting%5Bdirection%5D%5B%5D=false&sorting%5Bdirection%5D%5B%5D=false&sorting%5Bdirection%5D%5B%5D=false&sorting%5Bdirection%5D%5B%5D=false&sorting%5Bdirection%5D%5B%5D=false&sorting%5Bdirection%5D%5B%5D=false&sorting%5Bdirection%5D%5B%5D=false&sorting%5Bdirection%5D%5B%5D=false&sorting%5Bdirection%5D%5B%5D=false&sorting%5Bdirection%5D%5B%5D=false&sorting%5Bdirection%5D%5B%5D=false&sorting%5Bdirection%5D%5B%5D=false&sorting%5Bdirection%5D%5B%5D=false&sorting%5Bdirection%5D%5B%5D=false&sorting%5Bdirection%5D%5B%5D=false&isAjax=true";s:11:"script_name";s:10:"/index.php";}
```

I've researched and found that clearing bookmark_ui table might help but looking through PHPmyAdmin I can't even find the table.

I added an attribute to the columns 'free shipping' and it seems to have started since then, but unsure.

All the columns are visible but only a couple are selected - they shouldn't all be visible.[image]

Comment: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/6602#issuecomment-461025709
Follow this link to update column.php file. This will resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ended up being a faulty third party plugin issue which was resolved by them updating their code.

Answer (score -1):

This happened to me once and it ended up either being an issue with `max_execution_time`. *Flush cache and reindex* first to confirm that the issue isn't there and then try this:

1. Locate your `php.ini` using a `phpinfo.php` file.
2. As a user with `root` privileges, open `php.ini` in a text editor.
3. Locate the `max_execution_time` setting.
4. Change its value to `18000` (or `36000` if it is already 18000).
5. Save your changes to `php.ini` and exit the text editor.
6. Restart Apache:

   CentOS: `service httpd restart`

   Ubuntu: `service apache2 restart`